# Find weight of features for feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, distance

I have a data set of videos from which I need to recognize the emotion of the speaker. For that reason I have some markers on the face of the speaker. I detect their movement as the speaker speaks and for every frame find the change in the marker coordinates.

There are a total of 65 markers (blue dots) on the face of a speaker so at the end of one frame I have 130 (x and y coordinates) stored. I have chosen the mean and standard deviation of those points over the video sequence as my features (based on a paper published in 2009)

My question is from these 260 features per video (mean and standard deviation of each x and y coordinate) how do I reduce this to something more understandable or which produces a meaningful probability output(in my case an emotion). In the paper it used the plus l and take away r algorithm based on the Bhattacharyya Distance criterion but I just couldn't understand how to actually say one feature is better than another based on that criterion.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the paper? It might help us better understand the context.

Comment: @LCialdella Alright Ill add a link.

Comment: http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/P.Jackson/pub/avsp09/HaqJackson_AVSP09.pdf